# Swift Type "SceneName" does not conform to protocol ADInterstitialAdDelegate - SK Swift

Tags: swift, protocols

I cannotadd `ADInterstitialAdDelegate` to my class it says it does not conform to protocol...

```
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation
import iAd

var classicHScore: AnyObject? =     NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("classicHighscore")
var classicHScoreInt = classicHScore! as Int
var interstitialAd = ADInterstitialAd()

class SpeedGameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate, ADBannerViewDelegate, ADInterstitialAdDelegate {
```

No idea why i cannot find the answer on google but I'm sure one of you brainiacs will have the answer

i am using sprite kit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add the required delegate-methods. If you get such an error, check [the documentation of the Delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iAd/Reference/ADInterstitialAdDelegate_Ref/index.html) and check the required methods. These methods are marked with *Required*.

```
class SpeedGameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate, ADBannerViewDelegate, ADInterstitialAdDelegate {
    func interstitialAdDidUnload(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {

    }

    func interstitialAd(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect - Its been a long day overlooked that part - Star!